# Extracting a string and equal number of characters from both sides

Tags: javascript

I have this string

```
var string = "Economists estimate India to have been the most populous and wealthiest region of the world throughout the first millennium CE. This advantage was lost in the 18th century as other regions edged forward";
```

and a variable `var exp = "lost";` i would like to get 10 characters to the right and left of variable word lost. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of [substring](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) method and [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) method to achieve this.

```js
var string = "Economists estimate India to have been the most populous and wealthiest region of the world throughout the first millennium CE. This advantage was lost in the 18th century as other regions edged forward";
var exp = "lost";

var index = string.indexOf(exp);

var leftIndex = index - 10;
var rightIndex = index + 10;
var result = string.substring(leftIndex, rightIndex + exp.length);
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with [`String#substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

> The `substr()` method returns the characters in a string beginning at the specified location through the specified number of characters.

```js
var string = "Economists estimate India to have been the most populous and wealthiest region of the world throughout the first millennium CE. This advantage was lost in the 18th century as other regions edged forward",
    exp = "lost",
    part = string.substr(string.indexOf(exp) - 10, 20 + exp.length);

document.write(part);
```